# Calculate Pearson's Standardized Residuals in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to calculate Pearson's Standardized Residuals in Python (3.7.1) using the output of `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`. I already stumpled upon [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453729/what-is-the-equivalent-of-r-data-chisqresiduals-in-python) and it's exactly what I need, however I get erroneous results.  I can only guess that it has maybe to do with my newer Python Version (the link is from 2013)?

I already broke down the formula of the calculation of

`v = csum * rsum * (n - rsum) * (n - csum) / n**3`

into the terms `cr_sum = csum * rsum` and `n_rcsum = (n - rsum) * (n - csum)`. Both output arrays have the shape `(2,5)`. It seems to be necessary to calculate the Hadamard Product of `cr_sum` and `n_rcsum` here. When I did this by hand for the first cell (with the frequency value of 33) I ended up with the right residual (-2.62309082). However, I **can't get this Hadamard Product to work** in Python. Instead Python seems to to some broadcasting and outputs:

`array([[-1125512208,  -267063340,  -274153780, -1725637260,   691228240],
       [-1125512208,  -267063340,  -274153780, -1725637260,   691228240]])`.

Moreover I am generally confused about when to use which multiplication type. In the stackoverflow post the commentator only used the asterisk and everything seemed to work fine. What changes have to be made to the code and why?

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.contingency import margins
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

def residuals(observed, expected):
    return (observed - expected) / np.sqrt(expected)

def stdres(observed, expected):
    n = observed.sum()
    rsum, csum = margins(observed)
    v = csum * rsum * (n - rsum) * (n - csum) / n**3
    return (observed - expected) / np.sqrt(v)

F = np.array([[33, 250, 196, 136, 32], [55, 293, 190, 71, 13]])
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(F)
stdres = stdres(F,expected)
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged `R`?

Comment: *"... however I get erroneous results."*  I just reran the code from the linked question using Python 3.7.1, NumPy 1.16.2 and SciPy 1.2.1, and it works as expected.  Can you show the *exact* code that you used to get erroneous results?  Are you sure your input is a two-dimensional array (i.e. `observed.ndim` is 2)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I added the code that produces the error.

Comment: I get the error `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt` because there are negative values of which you can't take the square root. This also leads to `NaNs` in `stdres`

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce that error.  (By the way, you probably shouldn't save the return value of `stdres(F, expected)` in a variable called `stdres`, because that replaces the function name with the variable.)

Comment: By any chance are you running this on Windows?

Comment: Well this is indeed strange. Yes, I am running the code on Windows

Comment: I think I see the problem.  On Windows, the default integer type for a numpy array is 32 bits, and it looks like some of the intermediate integer calculations are overflowing.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on Windows? And do you know what I could do to solve that overflow problem?

Comment: Yes, you're right! When I convert F to `F = F.astype(np.int64)` everything works fine but this really exceeds my problem solving competences

Comment: @JohannesWiesner, you might be interested in my updated answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453729/what-is-the-equivalent-of-r-data-chisqresiduals-in-python, where I show how these calculations can be done using the `statsmodels` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the default integer type for a NumPy array is 32 bit.  When the code over at [What is the equivalent of R data.chisq$residuals in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453729/what-is-the-equivalent-of-r-data-chisqresiduals-in-python) is run on Windows with the input array `F = np.array([[33, 250, 196, 136, 32], [55, 293, 190, 71, 13]])`, the intermediate calculation of the expression `csum * rsum * (n - rsum) * (n - csum)` in the function `stdres` results in integer overflow.  The overflow puts negative negative values in the variable `v`, so when `sqrt(v)` is computed, you get `nan`s and a warning.

The fix is to convert `rsum` and `csum` to floating point before doing that intermediate calculation.  Try this version:

```
def stdres(observed, expected):
    n = observed.sum()
    rsum, csum = margins(observed)
    rsum = rsum.astype(np.float64)
    csum = csum.astype(np.float64)
    v = csum * rsum * (n - rsum) * (n - csum) / n**3
    return (observed - expected) / np.sqrt(v)
```

Comment: that solved the problem. I still don't understand **why** (or in other words why np.int32 is a problem) but I guess the explanation to this would exceed this post?

Comment: The largest signed 32 bit integer is `2**31-1` = 2147483647.  When the input is `F` as in your question, the result of the expression `csum * rsum * (n - rsum) * (n - csum)`  contains values that exceed that maximum.  When that happens, the overlfowed values "wrap around" to negative values.  Your idea to convert the input to `int64` is another way to solve the problem (but for big enough input vaues, it too would result in overflow).